# Python multiprocessing - only part of value returned instead of whole value

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am currently building my first multiprocessing application.

But.. Its not working. I tried to delete all the code to make it simple but I dont get it. 
Here is the Code:

```
itemList = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" ]

def printList(list):
    for item in list:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Single-Processing
    printList(itemList)

    #Multi-Processing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(printList, itemList)
```

Thats the output how it should be (when I do not run it with multiprocessing):

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
Item5
```

The output with multiprocessing:

```
I
t
e
m
1...
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You've failed to properly assign responsibility for iterating over your list. You're calling `pool.map`, which iterates over your list and calls `printList` on each element, but `printList` expects to receive the entire list and iterate over the list itself.

One of these loops has to go. You could stop iterating inside `printList`:

```
pool.map(print, itemList)
```

or you could stop using `map`:

```
pool.apply(printList, itemList)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pool.map` takes an iterable; you give it an iterable, so that's fine.

Your iterable is a list of strings.

What `pool.map` *does* with that iterable is to iterate through it:

```
for i in iterable:
    invoke_in_a_process(func, i)
```

where `invoke_in_a_process` bundles up the function and argument data and sends them through the pool to one of the process workers.  The worker then does, in effect:

```
func(i)
```

which passes a string to the functino.

The function is `printList` and the string is, e.g., `"Item1"`.  So, **exercise**: What does `printList` do when passed this string?

Comment: Right - or, said more in tune with the output, it iterates through each character in the string...